# How do I create different styles in one layer?

Tags: qgis, layers, line

I'm currently drawing canals (as a blue line feature) on a map. When a canal goes underground I want to change the line to a dashed line for instance.  How can I do this?
Is this possible within one layer? Or do I have to create an additional layer with a dashed line feature for underground canals?

Comment: Yes, if the underground parts are their own features and have an attribute stating they are underground. Does your layer fulfill that requirement? Alternatively a second layer with areas specifiying over- and underground would also be possible.

Comment: Even without an attribute it is possible in case of overlapping with another layer. Let's say: when the line overlaps a polygon: style 1, otherwise style 2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is well possible in one layer.

1. Open Layer Properties->Symbology and open a dropdown with Single Symbol value: [image]
2. Choose Categorized - features in the vector layers can be given attributes and you can set symbols in layers based on the values stored in Table od Attributes. You can add there an integer attribute called underground with value 1 for yesindeed and 0 for notatall.
   [image]
3. Open dropdown Value - here you will find all attribute fields for your layer. Qgis can classify your features with your choosen field and you will be able to set different symbols for that.
   [image]

There are more details here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation!

Comment: @Knut No problem! If my answer was enough, you may consider flagging it as "THE" answer. You can do it with this mark near the place where you up/down vote : p